# Get several days in select, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
|Number| Type | Date   |
| 1232 |   1  |1/1/2016|
| 2535 |   2  |1/1/2016|
| 5435 |   1  |2/1/2016|
| 344  |   2  |2/1/2016|
| ...  | ...  |5/1/2016|
```

And want a query that returns the data for last 5 days:

```
| Type |Date |Date -1|...    |Date -4|Date -5| 
|  1   | ... |....   |...    |  5435 |1232   |
|  2   | ... |....   |...    |  344  |2535   |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a code-wriing service, and even if it was you haven't made it clear what you need. Investigate hierarchical queries and pivots, depending on what you're really trying to achieve. Then see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pivot clause. 
for you base table have

```
select Number, Type, Date-Sysdate as Daysago from ...
```

then pivot using the pivot clause, something like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(      select Number, Type, Date-Sysdate as Daysago from ...)
PIVOT
(
 sum(Number)
 FOR product_id IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```